# Handle click event on a custom control that contains dynamically generated buttons vb.net

Tags: vb.net, button, click

**Here is my problem:**

I have a custom control that is a panel that dynamically generates buttons (in the future it will do enough things to be a control and not a mere panel)

What I want to do is a event in the form that contains the control which allows me to handle the clicks on that buttons.

How can I do this?

P.D. 1: More specifically I want to be able to know which button is being clicked

P.D. 2: In fact, if I'm able to handle a tag changed event in the panel it should be enough

Comment: Instead of posting comments to your own question, you could edit your post to further describe your question/problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a sub where you code goes

```
   Private Sub buttonPressed(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim b As Button = CType(sender, Button)
        MsgBox("Button pressed: " & b.Name)

    End Sub
```

When dynamically creating the button, add the following line of code:

```
  AddHandler yourButton.Click, AddressOf buttonPressed
```

Comment: Does it work even if the adressed function is in another class? Or can I use in the second class pannel_name.button pressed to handle that event?

Comment: Yes it should work if the addressed function is in another class. Just  make sure you declare the sub public instead of private and then use `AddHandler yourButton.Click, AddressOf yourClass.buttonPressed`

Answer (score 1):

You probably look for a custom event

```
Public Event ButtonPressed As EventHandler(Of ButtonPressedEventArgs)

Public Class ButtonPressedEventArgs 
    Inherits EventArgs
    Public Property MyButtonNumber As Integer
End Class
```

In a button click you raise the event

```
Private Sub MyButton1_Click(sender As System.Object,e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyButton1.Click
  RaiseEvent ButtonPressed(Me, New ButtonPressedEventArgs() with {.MyButtonNumber = 1}
End Sub
```

And handle the event where appropriate:

```
Private Sub MyControl_ButtonPressed(sender As System.Object,e As ButtonPressedEventArgs) Handles MyControl.ButtonPressed
    Select Case e.MyButtonNumber 
        Case 1
         'Do what required
    End Select 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code to handle the button's click event will look like this :

```
  Friend Sub Button1_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   'your code here
End Sub
```